# Angular Material Select - Want to link the mat-option values to larger outputs

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Select an option</mat-label>
  <mat-select [(value)]="selected">
    <mat-option>None</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="option1">Option 1</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="option2">Option 2</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="option3">Option 3</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>

<p>You selected: {{selected}}</p>
```

Id like to output more than Option 1, 2, 3 three if I select one of those values.
So a larger text should be appearing than. So Id like to choose a paragraph by the number an then output the whole paragraph if selected.
How could I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

U need to get your paragraphs and add all that to array. Next need to use *ngFor operator in template for iterate all paragraph list.
Check my example:

in html template

```html
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Select</mat-label>
  <mat-select>
    <!-- // here is we doing iteration all of paragraphs -->
    <ng-container *ngFor="let item of paragraphs">
      <mat-option value="item?.line"> {{ item?.name }}</mat-option>
    </ng-container>

  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>

<!-- increasing array length -->
<button mat-button (click)="addItems()"> Add Item</button>
```

and typescript code

```js
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

interface Paragraph {
  line: number;
  name: string;
};

/** @title Simple form field */
@Component({
  selector: 'form-field-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'form-field-overview-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['form-field-overview-example.css']
})

export class FormFieldOverviewExample {


  paragraphs : Paragraph[] = [];

  constructor () {

    this.paragraphs = [
      { line: 1, name: 'P1'},
      { line: 2, name: 'P2'},
      { line: 3, name: 'P3'}
    ];
  }

  addItems() {
    this.paragraphs.push( {line: this.paragraphs.length+1, name: 'P'+(this.paragraphs.length+1)})
  }
}
```

Comment: If u want to learn Angular I advise you to take a mini course https://angular.io/tutorial Here is all what u need to development for start

Answer (score 0):

As I understood your question, the aim here is to display a larger paragraph below the actual mat-select depending on currently selected value.
There are several approaches to achieve this aim. Since you are not using an array, but only the html template, you could use the ngSwitchCase directive:
https://angular.io/api/common/NgSwitchCase

Example:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Select an option</mat-label>
  <mat-select [(value)]="selected">
    <mat-option>None</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="option1">Option 1</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="option2">Option 2</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="option3">Option 3</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>

<div [ngSwitch]="selected">
    <p *ngSwitchCase="'option1'">Your long text 1 here</p>
    <p *ngSwitchCase="'option2'">Your long text 2 here</p>
    <p *ngSwitchDefault>Text when nothing is selected.</p>
</div>
```